# Asking for references on errors, testing, system failures etc

Tags: reference-request, software-engineering, software-testing, testing

I am looking for references that talk about the following subject:

Software programs are in general complex systems. That is, if we decompose them  into components and we make sure that each component is working correctly then we stil can have a lot of failures that arise from the interactions between the different components. Moreover, the assumption of being able to test separate component debatable. Often those components are also complex systems on their own. And even if we we test very small and indivisible components, we can still argue that making sure the component is working on 1000 cases (using unit testing for example) doesn't mean it's perfect. It probably have many hidden and undiscovered bugs.

Any book, talk, article, tweet etc. about the subject will help. Especially if it talks about how the community cope with this phenomenon.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds incredibly broad to me.  Any community votes?

Comment: You can start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing).